# Bayesian chronology building with archeology, genetics and linguistics

Tags: bayesian

Is it possible to predict the date distributions of historical events like Out Of Africa Migration?

I know that archeological findings already use a bayesian method to build a chronology with bayesian statistics. Is it possible to combine that with genetic data and linguistics into one quantitative chronology that can take hints from all of all of these different sources?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: not exactly what you're asking about, but an example of learning about a historical event from contemporary texts using Bayes: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14272

Comment: Thanks. This is great to know that this approach is also tried for reading texts. I updated the question to make it more focussed.